# Using Docker Registry Serivce Connection in Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, docker-registry

I've followed [this docs manual](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) to create a self-signed private registry on some VM. It works fine when I pull images from another host.

I now try to understand how I configure a Service Connection in Azure DevOps of type Docker Registry to use this registry.

This is my current setup:

[image]

And this is the log:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now?

Comment: Hi, I didn't quite understand your answer. Where is that "Docker's Settings"? Does that has anything to do with Docker Desktop? Because I don't use it, I use docker on ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

We could go to the Docker's Settings > Network and change DNS Server radio button to Fixed

[image]

In addition, I found a sample issue, you could also check [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611).